# Checking if value of a string exceeds a value

Tags: android, textview

In my app, I have a speedometer class and I want to be able to say in my Broadcast Receiver class that when the speed goes over 25, do some action.
How would I go about doing that?
I have searched various questions but all lead me to a dead end.
Heres the Speedometer Code

```
package com.rrithvik.idrive;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Created by vipul on 12/13/2015.
 */
public class LocationService extends Service implements
        LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final long INTERVAL = 1000 * 2;
    private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 1000 * 1;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mCurrentLocation, lStart, lEnd;
    static double distance = 0;
    double speed;


    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        createLocationRequest();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        return mBinder;
    }

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        try {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
        }
    }


    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);
        distance = 0;
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        MainActivity.locate.dismiss();
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        if (lStart == null) {
            lStart = mCurrentLocation;
            lEnd = mCurrentLocation;
        } else
            lEnd = mCurrentLocation;

        //Calling the method below updates the  live values of distance and speed to the TextViews.
        updateUI();
        //calculating the speed with getSpeed method it returns speed in m/s so we are converting it into kmph
        speed = location.getSpeed() * 2.24;

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {

        public LocationService getService() {
            return LocationService.this;
        }


    }

    //The live feed of Distance and Speed are being set in the method below .
    private void updateUI() {
        if (MainActivity.p == 0) {
            distance = distance + (lStart.distanceTo(lEnd) * 0.00062);
            MainActivity.endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long diff = MainActivity.endTime - MainActivity.startTime;
            diff = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diff);
            MainActivity.time.setText("Total Time: " + diff + " minutes");
            if (speed > 0.0) {
                MainActivity.speed.setText("Current speed: " + new DecimalFormat("#.##").format(speed) + " mph");
            }
            else {
                MainActivity.speed.setText(".......");
            }
            MainActivity.dist.setText("Total Distance " + new DecimalFormat("#.###").format(distance) + " miles.");

            lStart = lEnd;

        }

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        stopLocationUpdates();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        lStart = null;
        lEnd = null;
        distance = 0;
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }
}
```

So once again, this action has to be done in the Broadcast Receiver Class

Comment: Where's this `String` and `BroadcastReceiver` that you mention?

Comment: Theres a textView called MainActivity.speed

Comment: The Broadcast Receiver is a whole other class

Comment: So use `Integer.parseInt` on the string and then do the comparison.

Comment: My question is how I can check if the speed is greater than 25. Right now it's defined as a String so I can't really do anything to fix my issue.

Comment: convert your string to a double, and check if it's value is > than 25.

Comment: @VladMatvienko how would I go about doing that

Comment: Double.parseDouble(your_string);

Comment: `how would I go about doing that` - how about using search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are searching

`double speedNum = Double.parseDouble(speed)`

and then do the checking whether the speedNum is larger than 25 or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your String to a Double value, you will can verify this number.

```
double speedDouble = Double.parseDouble(speedText);
if(speedDouble > 25) {
// Do something
}
```